# Is there a way of inserting data to database with many-to-many relationship in Prisma?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, prisma

I have tried using `connect` and `connectOrCreate` but it did not work, because for each insertion of purchase it may have many products, so my idea is to insert many products of each purchase.
For example, for each purchase there will have product 1, product 2, product 3 and etc. I want to pass array of data/json containing these products and then insert int the three tables at once.

**These are my models:**

```
model Category {
  id      Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  name    String    @unique @db.VarChar(50)
  product Product[]

  @@map("categories")
}

model Product {
  id         Int         @id @default(autoincrement())
  name       String      @unique @db.VarChar(35)
  barcode    String      @unique @db.VarChar(35)
  sell  Decimal     @db.Decimal(12, 2)
  shop Decimal     @db.Decimal(12, 2)
  quantity Int
  expiresIn String
  createdAt  DateTime    @default(now())
  updatedAt  DateTime    @updatedAt
  categoryId Int
  category   Category    @relation(fields: [categoryId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: Cascade)
  sales      SaleOrder[]
  purchases PurchaseProduct[]
  
  @@map("products")
}

model PurchaseProduct{
  name  String    @db.VarChar(50)
  sell  Decimal       @db.Decimal(12, 2)
  shop Decimal        @db.Decimal(12, 2)
  quantity Int
  expiresIn String
  purchaseId Int
  purchase   Purchase    @relation(fields: [purchaseId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: Cascade)
  productId Int
  product   Product    @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: Cascade)

  @@id([purchaseId, productId])

  @@map("purchaseProducts")
}


model Purchase{
   id   Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  supplierId Int
  supplier   Supplier    @relation(fields: [supplierId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: Cascade)
  createdAt  DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt  DateTime @updatedAt

  purchases PurchaseProduct[]
  @@map("purchases")
}

model Supplier {
  id          Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  name        String    @unique @db.VarChar(35)
  email       String?   @unique @db.VarChar(35)`your text`
  contact String?   @unique @db.VarChar(10)
  products    Purchase[]

  @@map("suppliers")
}
```

**What I have tried:**

```
export async function create(formData: Purchase){
  const purchase = await db.purchase.create({
    data:   {
      name: formData.name,
      sell: formData.sell,
      shop: formData.shop,
      quantity: formData.quantity,
      supplier: {
                  connectOrCreate:{
                    where:{name: formData.supplierName},
                    create:{name: formData.supplierName, contact: formData.phone, email: formData.email}
                }
              },
      product:{
                connectOrCreate:{where:{name:formData.name}, 
                create:{
                      name: FormData.name,
                      barcode: formData.barcode,
                      sell:formData.sell,
                      shop: formData.shop,
                      quantity: formData.quantity,
                      expiresIn: formData.expiresIn,
                      categoryId: formData.categoryId
                    }}
                }}
              })
              
  return purchase;
}
```